# Spring integration with retry with ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy

Tags: spring-integration, spring-retry

I am using `int:request-handler-advice-chain` with my service activator. It is working correctly with `org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy` however I would like to use `org.springframework.retry.policy.ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` to allow for a different number of retries based on the exception thrown by the service activator.

The problem I am having is that by the time the exception gets to the `ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` it is a

> org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException

Can anyone advise on the best approach for get the cause (i.e my exception) from the `MessageHandlingException` made available to the `ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy`?

Solution thanks to Artem's suggestion below:

Create a subclass of SubclassClassifier that returns the cause in the case of MessagingException

```
public class MessagingCauseExtractingSubclassClassifier extends SubclassClassifier<Throwable, RetryPolicy> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessagingCauseExtractingSubclassClassifier.class);

    public MessagingCauseExtractingSubclassClassifier(final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, RetryPolicy> policyMap, final RetryPolicy retryPolicy) {
        super(policyMap, retryPolicy);
    }

    @Override
    public RetryPolicy classify(final Throwable throwable) {
        Throwable t = throwable;
        if (t instanceof MessagingException) {
            t = t.getCause();
            LOG.debug("Throwable is instanceof MessagingException so classifying cause type: {}", t.getClass());
        }
        return super.classify(t);
    }
}
```

Then a new ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy subclass that uses the new classifier and policyMap

```
public class MessasgeCauseExtractingExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy extends ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy {

    @Override
    public void setPolicyMap(final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, RetryPolicy> policyMap) {
        final MessagingCauseExtractingSubclassClassifier classifier = new MessagingCauseExtractingSubclassClassifier(
                policyMap, new NeverRetryPolicy());
        setExceptionClassifier(classifier);
    }
}
```

Currently this won't support retying on MessagingException but this is fine for our use case. Otherwise works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BinaryExceptionClassifier` has `traverseCauses` option to analize the whole StackTrace until the proper condition.

Exactly this option is with one of `SimpleRetryPolicy` constructor:

```
public SimpleRetryPolicy(int maxAttempts, Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions,
        boolean traverseCauses) {
```

Please, take a look if that variant is feasible for you.

Comment: Thanks Artem, this is certainly in the right direction the only problem is that SimpleRetryPolicy doesn't allow for different maxAttempts based on the Exception type.

Comment: OK. So, I suggest you to implement your own ... `SubclassClassifier` similar to `BinaryExceptionClassifier` but returning the proper `RertyPolicy` on good condition for the `cause`